# Cakephp Model and Database Conventions

Tags: cakephp

I just wondering for table field naming e.g. first_name.

in the data model. Is it ok i name as first_name also?

Or must i change to firstName?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which naming convention you use is entirely up to you, just so long as its not an invalid one (including spaces, etc). Go with what is most easily understood by you and your team.

Answer (score 5):

Field names should use underscores according to the CakePHP conventions, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/24/Model-and-Database-Conventions

Answer (score 0):

since this field is not a primary key or a foreign key, there is no problem